# Spotlight can't find files

Tags: spotlight

As in the title: Spotlight can't find any files on my Mac. It was working before and got broken for no apparent reason (I didn't update the OS, install any app or tamper with settings). It still finds apps, converts currencies etc. I've tried to force reindex as described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716) and [here](https://www.drbuho.com/how-to/rebuild-spotlight-index) (using mdutil) and it didn't help. Also, searching in the Mail app got broken at the same time. I'm using Ventura 13.0.1. Does anyone know what else I can do, apart from reinstalling the system?

Comment: How about the Finder? Can you able to search for files and folders successfully in the Finder?

Comment: Yes, it works fine.